# Enabling Workbench in sandbox

Tags: workbench

We have three sandboxes attached to production.Would enabling workbench in one sandbox effects other non prod enviorment also.
Can it be possible we enable it for one sandbox and other two sandboxes have it disabled.

Will change migration of components have any effect for this.

Thanks
Arun Sharma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workbench is a third party application used to connect to your Salesforce org(Production/Sandbox) using SOAP/REST/Metadata/Bulk APIs.

Its not enabled for entire organization but per user basis. If a user logs into Workbench it won't get enabled for others users.

Just like above point, its enabled per user per organization. Its possible that one user from one sandbox used Workbench and the same user in another sandbox not used Workbench.

So while logging in you should select for which environment(Production/Sandbox) you are trying to log in. For best experience, first log in to environment(Production/Sandbox) and then login to Workbench so it can use the current sessionid and log you in to Workbench for that that specific Production/Sandbox.

[image]

In change migration perspective, there won't be any issues as it just uses your metadata and won't update your metadata.

Hope this helps to understand better.

Comment: +++this post :    In addition, you just have to make sure you select the correct environment to login to Workbench as.  It defaults to production.

Comment: @DavidLitton: Thanks. Added image for better understandability.

Comment: If the provided answer solved your problem, please mark it as best answer so that other users with same problem gets benefit.Thanks